# Can BigQuery report mismatched the schema field?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I upsert a row that mismatches schema I get a `PartialFailureError` along with a message, e.g.:

```
[ { errors: 
     [ { message: 'Repeated record added outside of an array.',
         reason: 'invalid' } ],
   ...
]
```

However for large rows this isn't sufficient, because I have no idea which field is the one creating the error. The `bq` command does report the malformed field.

Is there either a way to configure or access name of the offending field, or can this be added to the API endpoint?

Comment: This should be already in the API as well. Just look how you parse your errors. You didn't named the library you are using.

Comment: I'm using the NodeJS library, and its [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/insert) just points me back to the [troubleshooting errors page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors).

"The `errors` property contains detailed information about why each unsuccessful row failed.", the field I am looking at above, and which does not provide the name of the field that is causing the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More detailed error messages from Node.js BigQuery client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272745/more-detailed-error-messages-from-node-js-bigquery-client-library)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Github Issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/issues/70 . Apparently node.js client library is not getting the `location` field from the API so it's not able to return it to the caller.

Workaround that worked for me: I copied the JSON payload to my Postman client and manually sent a request to REST API (let me know if you need more details of how to do it).